# SAS: program path in SAS RSUBMIT

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to get the pathname where program is saved when we do RSUBMIT.

Eg: we can get the pathname in SAS EG or SAS Studio from macro variable &_SASPROGRAMFILE.

Is there a macro variable equivalent to &_SASPROGRAMFILE  when we do RSUBMIT.

Comment: You have the program, otherwise what are you remote submitting? RSUBMIT just sends the code. If you have a different use case please explain it in detail.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You could use the %SYSLPUT function to pass something to a macro variable in the remote session.  Not sure what you want to pass it however.  The program you are "running" is the one on the local machine, it might not even be accessible on the remote machine.